# 12.04 continuously offering partial upgrade

Tags: partial-upgrade

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity and for the last 3 months or so it's been offering me a partial upgrade. The only things that cannot be upgraded are the kernel and dropbox. I'm still on the 3.2.0-37-generic-pae kernel. On my another machine (12.04 with MATE) I had the same problem but it disappeared on its own. What should I do to go on with normal life?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-ger dist-upgrade` in a terminal and if that does not resolve the problem, post the error message.

Comment: Try in terminal: `sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Yeah! After reading your suggestions I dared to dist-uprgade, (although previously I've been very much afraid that it would screw up my system). And it really worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Run sudo `apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` in a terminal

NOTE: "dist-upgrade" does NOT upgrade the system to a new version of Ubuntu.

See man apt-get for details

> dist-upgrade

```
       dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
       also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
       of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
       it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
       expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade
       command may therefore remove some packages. The
       /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of locations from which
       to retrieve desired package files. See also apt_preferences(5) for
       a mechanism for overriding the general settings for individual
       packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of adding some new repositories to your software sources. I had the same problem but I removed some repositories like libreoffice4-2 and now there no partial upgrade offering to me!